# How to produce a compilation error if a pointer to a particular object is deleted?

Tags: c++

I have a pretty large and verbose codebase and I am trying to find a trick to discover if an object of a particular class has gone through a `delete` anywhere in the code, preferably by giving me a compilation error if this is the case.
I found out that you can overload the delete operator as in: `void operator delete(void*)` and put this in the private section of the class of interest (so that whenever there is `delete` on a pointer of that class it will fail compilation).

This could be the perfect solution, but alas it emits an error also when I use `new` on that object. The compiler probably tries to generate the delete operator automatically once a `new` is present. I don't want to alert on the `new CLASS` appearances, just the `delete`.

Any other ideas what I can do?

Comment: Do you mean compile-time analysis or run-time?

Comment: Forbid the default destructor by `delete`ing it?

Comment: _Any other ideas what I can do?_ My codebase was written when I was young (OK, well, maybe not so young) and ignorant, and used `new` and `delete` extensively.  So, a few months ago, I decided to bite the bullet and clean up my act.  A lot of hard work later, and a bit of time fixing some newly introduced bugs (which I knew was bound to happen), and I'm now in a much better place.  I don't know if this might be viable for you, but it has to be worth considering.  You can't build castles on sand.

Comment: I'd also argue that you are incorrect in focusing on removing use of `delete` from your code but still using `new`.   Modern guidelines are to avoid doing EITHER.  This is why, for example, there is a templated function `std::make_unique()` to create `std::unique_ptr` objects - it dynamically creates the object but your code avoids using EITHER `new` or `delete` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `new` an object for which the corresponding `operator delete` is unusable because construction of the new object or the initializer of the new-expression may throw exceptions and then the `new` expression must be able to call `operator delete` to free the memory again.

Also note that often the global allocation and deallocation functions are used explicitly, so that your class-specific overload will be ignored. (Specifically with `::new` and `::delete` instead of `new` and `delete`.)

Furthermore, a lot of library functions (e.g. allocator-aware containers) do not use allocating `new`/`delete` expressions to construct dynamic storage duration objects, but instead allocate untyped memory first and then use placement-news and explicit destructor calls to construct and destroy objects. In this case also often the global allocation/deallocation functions are used explicitly.

You can't in general forbid specifically destruction of *dynamic* storage duration objects of a class type. A class should generally be agnostic to how its lifetime is managed. You can only e.g. delete the destructor, but then almost all uses of the class will be impossible.

You can of course also simply make an accessible overload of `operator new` and `operator delete` (as well as the array overloads `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]`) in the class and log calls to them at runtime by having them e.g. print a message. But as mentioned above this will still not catch a lot of cases, only uses of `delete` (and `delete[]`) exactly and it will also log cases of a `new` expression calling `operator delete`.